# Передача вектора в функцию, начиная с определенного элемента

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то передать вектор в функцию, начиная с определенного элемента? Поясню: имея один массив a, можно спокойно передавать его в функцию f, скажем, вот так: f(a, a + n, ...), то есть в теле функции это будут как разные массивы. Можно ли то же самое сделать с векторами?

Comment: Обычно в стандартной библиотеке это решается парой итераторов - начало и элемент за концом. В современном С++ также можно использовать ranges

Comment: А можете привести пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Пример чего, стандартной библиотеки? `std::sort()` подойдет?

Comment: При использовании массива всё равно не массив передаётся, а указатели на элементы. Для контейнеров такими "указателями" являются итераторы.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря как описана функция.

Как

```
void func(const vector<int>& v);
```

тогда придется потрудиться (например, создавая новый вектор), а вот если

```
void func(vector<int>::iterator b, vector<int>::iterator e);
```

то что-то вроде

```
func(v.begin() + m, v.begin() + n);
```

например...

Вы бы уточнили, что именно хотите получить.

Comment: Я считываю матрицу из файла, которая хранится там в профильном формате, в один массив, т.е массивы ig, di, ggl, ggu просто хранятся последовательно друг за другом. Но в функцию мне их нужно передавать как разные массивы, поэтому я хотел передавать один и тот же вектор в функцию, но начиная с нужного мне индекса выдавать его за несколько векторов.

Comment: Тогда лучше использовать итераторы (или, раз это вектор, индексы).